# Why INSERT INTO doesn't work in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sql-insert, insert-into

i have problem with SQLite3 in Python (using PyCharm + Python 3.5 on W10). The insert doesn't work

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("DROP TABLE Normal;") # to clean data
c.execute("CREATE TABLE Normal (Invoice INTEGER);")
c.execute("INSERT INTO Normal (Invoice) VALUES (24);")
```

If I run sqlite3.exe in the directory afterwards, open the db and write commands in cmd.exe console:

```
sqlite> .open test.db;
sqlite> select * from Normal;
sqlite> INSERT INTO Normal (Invoice) VALUES (24);
sqlite> select * from Normal;
24
```

The very same insert works. I am confused...

Comment: Are there any error messages?

Comment: Have you tried to do a `COMMIT`?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not specific enough. Add details.

Comment: See about [using the connection as a context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The python library of SQLITE3 is transactional, meaning that it doesn't commit to the database until you commit the changes.

after the INSERT INTO statement put the line:

```
conn.commit()
```